# Заменить строку в текстовом файле

Tags: java, android

Подскажите пожалуйста на примере, как заменить строку в текстовом файле, и желательно чтобы файл не разрушился при аварийном сбое программы..

Вот набросал код, подправьте пожалуйста, чувствую что лишнего нагородил..

```
try {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(filepath_forDeskMap));
   List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
   int ii = 0;
   while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
       lines.add(sc.nextLine());
       ii++;
   }
       lines.set("Произведена замена на эту строку !");

       File file = new File(filepath_forDeskMap); //Создаем файловую переменную
       // открываем поток для записи
       BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
       // пишем данные
       for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
           if(i != lines.size()-1){
           bw.write(lines.get(i) + "\n");}else{
               bw.write(lines.get(i));
           }
       }
       // закрываем поток
       bw.close();

   } catch (Exception e1) {
   }
```

Comment: После чтения строк в список нужно закрыть сканнер. И лучше ( _чтобы файл не разрушился при аварийном сбое программы_ ) запись делать не в тот же файл, а другой. После удачной записи оригинал удалить, а копию переименовать в оригинал.